# JDBC sql query (batch processing)

Tags: java, database, jdbc

i want to make a batch update(100 resords) and batch insert(50 records) with jdbc in java using a single statement like i want to hit the database just once. How can i do that?

Comment: Before asking, please show us what you have tried.

Comment: There are a lot of examples in the internet: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/jdbc/batchupdate.html

Answer (score 2):

In java you have something called as prepared statement.In the prepared statement you have addBatch() and executeBatch() methods.
These methods can be helpful in your case.
Here is an example :
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/batch-insert-in-java-jdbc/